# How to remove watermark from image from the product grid in magento2?

Tags: magento2, catalog, watermark

I have uploaded one product using csv with base,small and thumbnail images.

I am not getting watermark images for base and small but for thumbnail image which are used in product grid.

So how to remove watermark from it?

[image]

Comment: check it in theme configuration watermark for thumbnail, if it has watermark images just remove it.

Comment: It was removed in all the thumbnail of the product.

Comment: @Rutvee, Did you get any solution for this?